# Ssh-add and contacting server unsuccessfully

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, ssh-keys, private-key

I forgot how to do this procedure.

I did on OSX 10.9.1

- run `ssh-keygen` in my server
- moved the private-key id_rsa to my laptop's `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa`, removed the private key id_rsa from my server
- create the following `$HOME/.ssh/config` in my laptop
- run `ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa`

My .ssh/config

```
Host server.myhomepage.com
  User masi
  Port 22
  Hostname server.myhomepage.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  TCPKeepAlive yes
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I run

```
ssh-add .ssh/id_rsa 
Enter passphrase for .ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: .ssh/id_rsa (.ssh/id_rsa)
```

and running more

```
ssh server.myhomepage.com
Saving password to keychain failed
```

and it asked my passphrase for my id_rsa in a graphical window which I gave correctly but get **failed** message.
Then, it asks in the terminal if I enter correctly the password for my private key but showed still the **failed** message.
I run many times with correct password

```
Identity added: /Users/masi/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/masi/.ssh/id_rsa)
masi@server.myhomepage.com's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I forgot how to do this procedure correctly.
**How can you have the key in your keychain correctly?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the client side, you need both the private and the public part of the key.

On the server side, you need to have the public part of the key in `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

So the steps that are missing in your description are:

- copy the public key to the laptop's `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- add the public key to the server's `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Don't forget to set the keyfile and directory permissions correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Works well with these changes!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you're on OSX with Mavericks. This apple support forum message seems very relevant:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5470737?btstart=0

It would appear you need to 'massage' the key generated by ssh-keygen into a form that the OSX patched openssh can work with.

Potentially, it could be this situation instead:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106364/osx-ssh-agent-no-password-pasting-and-problem-with-pkcs8

If you continue to have problems, please add the top three lines of the private key, the ones that look like this:

```
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
  DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,3EA2BF123CB9E67FBB094A12A82E7BAF
```

Incidentally, I'd be amused to know if you have an environment variable present called SSH_ASKPASS. That, in theory, should be how the apple ssh-add is invoking a graphical password prompt.

Good Luck!